# Unbinding key using use-package

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

I'm trying unbind  `org-cycle-agenda-files` which is set by default to  `C-'` and `C-,`.

My weapon of choice to do so is [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package.

On  [github.com/use-package/bind-key.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el)
 page I have found following lines:

```
;; To unbind a key within a keymap (for example, to stop your favorite major
;; mode from changing a binding that you don't want to override everywhere),
;; use `unbind-key':
;;
;;   (unbind-key "c-c x" some-other-mode-map)
```

This resulted in me unsuccessfully trying following variations:

```
(unbind-key "C-'" )
(unbind-key "C-," )
(unbind-key "C-'" (org-cycle-agenda-files))
(unbind-key "C-," (org-cycle-agenda-files))
(bind-keys :map org-mode-map
       :unbind "C-'")
(unbind-key "C-'" org-cycle-agenda-files)
```

After that fail I triyed some "traditional" solution to the problem.

Information found in [gnu.org manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html), and some [emacs.stackexchange answers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html) resulted in me producing following useless havoc:

```
(define-key (org-cycle-agenda-files) key nil)
(define-key (current-global-map) "C-'" nil)
(local-unset-key "C-'")
(global-unset-key "C-'")
(with-eval-after-load org-mode
  (unbind-key "C-'" org-mode-map)
  (unbind-key "C-," org-mode-map))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'nil)
```

Yep.... None these variations vorks. :D

I would love to find [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) based solution, since I'm already using some of it's awesome capabilities.

Any kind of suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you <kbd>C-h f</kbd> and enter `unbind-key`, the help says:

> unbind-key is an autoloaded Lisp macro in `bind-key.el'.
>
> (unbind-key KEY-NAME &optional KEYMAP)
>
> Not documented.

The second argument to `unbind-key` is a key map -- for example `org-mode-map`.

This works for me:

```
(require 'bind-key)
(unbind-key "C-," org-mode-map)
(unbind-key "C-'" org-mode-map)
```

A good place to put this would be the `:config` section of a `use-package` form.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah the unbinding does not look elegant, but that's the main approach according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7549357/4780877).

As for use-package, I have been using unbind under :init directive like so:

```
:init
(unbind-key "C-'" org-mode-map)
(unbind-key "C-," org-mode-map)
```

Comment: You need to put this inside `:config`, and not `:init`, because in `:init` the keymap may not be loaded yet.

Comment: `:config` didn't work for me. According to the [use-package docs](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#binding-within-local-keymaps), you should use `:bind` with `:map`

Comment: The `:config` option works for me. The option to set `nil` in mode-map do not remove keys form listing, just set them nil. The `:config` option clear keys from map

Answer (score 4):

Using `use-package`'s `:bind` by setting the binding to `nil` worked for me in similar cases, but I use it with `:straight org-plus-contrib` and I do not know if this approach applies the same with built-in `org`:

```lisp
(use-package org
  :straight org-plus-contrib
  :bind (:map org-mode-map 
         ("C-," . nil)
         ("C-'" . nil)))
```